# Python 3.x read text file without ignoring blank line at the end

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I've tried to read a text file that look something like that:

```
Line 1

Line 3
```

Using the following code:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        print("~ " + line)
```

But the loop runs only 3 times instead of 4, Ignoring the blank line.

The output I get is:

```
~ Line 1
~ 
~ Line 3
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Tried adding another line?

Comment: Did you mean `f_in.close()` where you have `f_in.closed`? Please post the actual code that you are using

Comment: Is the last line a new line?

Comment: Please post `repr(open('textfile.txt', 'rb').read())` so we can see the exact contents of `textfile.txt`.

Comment: The last line at textfile.txt is a new line.
The content of the file is 3 lines with text and then an empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a file as an iterator, the end of a line is marked by `\n`.  Which means that even though your editor may show a "blank line" after the `3`, if there is no data there, there is no line there.

For example, try this:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(b'1\n\n3\n4')

with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        print("~ " + line)
```

By putting the character `4` on that last line, even with no terminating linefeed, Python recognizes another line.  Without that `4`, you only have three lines.